# Last-Modified Header Timestamp Not Reliable?

Tags: http-headers

I was working on a project dealing with the Last-Modified time of photos from various websites. One of the websites drew my attention with the fact that all of its product photos being requested had the same Last-Modified header as Wed, 20 Jan 1988 04:20:42 GMT in the response headers. (See photo below)
[image]

The timestamp looks really strange to me because year 1988 is a year when internet and png/jpeg photo format (product photos of the website) did not even exist yet. I need to evaluate the validity of the timestamp for the project but I really want to understand more before simply saying it's a fake time. There're some thoughts in my mind that could not be wrapped in one question so I'm just listing them out as follows:

1. From a high level, where does the last-modified timestamp come from, is it from the last-modified field from the file system?
2. The company started in 1986 based on their company profile, so it's still possible to have some digital photos in storage at year 1988. Would it be technically possible that the original photos were created in 1988, stored and served later when internet becomes available?
3. In response headers, the Date property is actually reflecting correctly the current date when I requested the resource. Does that justify the validity of the time or it's also possible that the server time got changed back and forth somewhere in the middle?
4. Its product photos are png or jpeg and with resolutions up to the standard of today, how did they manage to do that without altering the last-modified metadata if we assume the timestamp is still valid? Note: they seem to all have the same timestamp precisely.

As mentioned, I'm still trying to understand more under the hood, so if you have any thoughts on how I could continue digging into this, that'll be helpful as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are no obvious answers to these questions. You’ll have to ask the people who built the site.

Photo metadata is 100% under the control of the developers / operators of the site. If you wanted to use file system timestamps, you could. If you wanted to substitute a timestamp from another source, or a made-up time stamp, you could.

You might be able to find a clue by downloading photos and examining the EXIF metadata that’s embedded in the image data. That’s another potential source of the timestamp data. But of course that could also be doctored.